# How can I get first class tag using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I would like to scrape the fund price and date of the following url: https://www.blackrock.com/sg/en/products/241427/blackrock-cont-european-flexible-d4rf-gbp-fund
and put these values in a table:

```
    Date       Price
21-Oct-2021    36.68
```

However, in the html source there are many <span class with the same title:

```
<span class="header-nav-label navAmount">
NAV as of 21-Oct-2021
</span>
<span class="header-nav-data">
GBP 36.68
</span>
<span class="header-nav-data">
0.10
(0.27%)
</span>
```

But I only want to pick the first class with the daily price in it.

I've tried the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Create url list
urls = ['https://www.blackrock.com/sg/en/products/241427/blackrock-cont-european-flexible-d4rf-gbp-fund']

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'}

# Build the scraping loop
for url in urls:
    # Extract HTML element (daily price and date) from url 
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    spans = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'header-nav-data'})
    for span in spans:
       print (span.text)
    spans1 = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'header-nav-label navAmount'})
    print (spans1)
```

which returns:

```
GBP 36.8
0.1
(0.27%)
[<span class="header-nav-label navAmount">
NAV as of 21-Oct-2021
</span>]
```

What do I need to do to only select the first <span class as I'm only interested about the price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution using css selectors.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Create url list
urls = ['https://www.blackrock.com/sg/en/products/241427/blackrock-cont-european-flexible-d4rf-gbp-fund']

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'}

# Build the scraping loop
for url in urls:
    # Extract HTML element (daily price and date) from url
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    spans1 = soup.select_one('ul.values-list li span:nth-child(1)').get_text(strip=True).replace('NAV as of', ' ')
    spans2 = soup.select_one('ul.values-list li span:nth-child(2)').get_text(strip=True).replace('GBP', ' ')
    
    print('Date:'+spans1)
    print('Price:' +spans2)
```

Output:

```
Date:  21-Oct-2021
Price:  36.68
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also go the path of pulling out the json within the html:

```
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.blackrock.com/sg/en/products/241427/blackrock-cont-european-flexible-d4rf-gbp-fund'
response = requests.get(url)

regex = r"(var navData = )(\[.*)(;)"
jsonStr = re.search(regex, response.text).groups()[1]
jsonStr = re.sub(r"((x:)(Date.UTC\(\d{4},\d{1,2},\d{1,2}\)),y:Number\({1,2})([\d.]*)([).\s\w\(]*)", r"\2\4", jsonStr)
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace('x:','"y":')
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace('formattedX:','"Date":')
jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData)
df = df[['Date','y']]
```

**Output:**

to the most recent, just do `print(df.tail(1))`

```
print(df)
                  Date      y
0     Thu, 13 Sep 2012   9.81
1     Fri, 14 Sep 2012  10.07
2     Mon, 17 Sep 2012  10.02
3     Tue, 18 Sep 2012   9.94
4     Wed, 19 Sep 2012   9.96
               ...    ...
2275  Fri, 15 Oct 2021  36.30
2276  Mon, 18 Oct 2021  36.43
2277  Tue, 19 Oct 2021  36.48
2278  Wed, 20 Oct 2021  36.58
2279  Thu, 21 Oct 2021  36.68

[2280 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
soup.find_all('span', class='header-nav-label navAmount')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use limit=1 [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Create url list
urls = ['https://www.blackrock.com/sg/en/products/241427/blackrock-cont-european-flexible-d4rf-gbp-fund']

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'}

# Build the scraping loop
for url in urls:
    # Extract HTML element (daily price and date) from url 
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    spans = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'header-nav-data'})
    print(spans)
    print('----------------------------')
    spans = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'header-nav-data'}, limit=1)
    print(spans)
    print('---------------------')
    print(spans[0].text)
    # or
    for span in spans:
       print (span.text)
    spans1 = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'header-nav-label navAmount'})
    print (spans1)
```